# Simple 3-column fluid layout, but center column empty with fixed-width?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Tricky to find the most cross-browser-compatible solution (IE6 included).

Three columns, the two on the sides are responsive and adjust with screen.

The middle column should be **empty**, but with a **fixed width**:

[image]

It's easy to make them all responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/sZehH/2/ (in this case, the middle one isn't even a column but just a margin — which is nice).

```
<section> 
    <div>
        <p>Column 1, lorem ipsum dolor bla bla dogs and cats</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Best if Column 2 is a margin or something -->
    <div>
        <p>Column 3, lorem blops dolor bla laa cats and dogs</p>                        
    </div>
<section>
```

I've considered using `position:`, but it can get messy...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an inner element for spacing? Could be another DIV tag inside each column:

http://jsfiddle.net/sZehH/3/

HTML:

```
<section> 
    <div class="left">
        <p>Column 1, lorem ipsum dolor bla bla dogs and cats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <p>Column 3, lorem blops dolor bla laa cats and dogs</p>                        
    </div>
<section>
```

​CSS:

```
section div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;

}

section div p {
    background: pink;
    padding: 2.5%;    
}

.left p {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.right p {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I've used the paragraphs that where already there, but you probably will have more than one element, so you will have to add a wrapping element to account for that.
​

Comment: Ah, great idea! I think we have a winner. Though I think IE6 will not like the margins (for no good reason of course)? **Also**, instead of a wrapping element, I can just make a catch-all CSS argument (e.g. `.right p, .right h1, .right div {margin-left:20px;`}), correct?

Comment: **Update:** It seems that it'll work with everything but `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/sZehH/4/ — which gets a white margin instead of the pink. In this case I won't have a `div` anyway, but am curious to sort this out.

Comment: The trick is that the element must have `display: block`, like divs and the background color must be placed in this elements, instead of the outer ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is box-sizing. While it is not technically supported for older browsers, it does have [polyfills](http://html5please.com/#box-sizing).

Check out [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afhjw/) To the following:

CSS (vendor prefixes excluded):

```
html, body {
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
}    

#columnOne, #columnTwo {
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#columnOne {
    float:left;
    border-right: 20px solid blue;
}

#columnTwo {
    float: right;
    border-left: 20px solid blue;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>        

        <div id="columnOne">HI!</div>
        <div id="columnTwo">HI!</div>

    </body>
</html>  ​
```

More info [here](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and info on polyfills [here](http://html5please.com/#box-sizing).

Have fun!

Comment: News to me :D Looks cool! Thanks. A question, I just added `* {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}` to my CSS, but nothing changed visibly on the page. As I understood it, shouldn't all elements have become smaller? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm really liking your solution Apttap, though this seems easier: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/sZehH/5/ — but will it blend? (i.e., IE6)

Comment: What's the browser you're using? What properties do you have assigned to your columns? If there's no padding or border, then no they won't change size. The other solution is indeed viable, but the border-box thing seems more semantic.

Comment: Checked on Safari and Chrome, and most elements have margins and padding.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly declaring the `box-sizing: border-box` for each css element you want to test in order to verify that it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Given your strict browser support requirements you may need to use non-semantic `tables`. This `table` solution, though you might already know it, can be viewed on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk29A/2/) or below. Oh, and I haven't tested it, but as far as I know all of this should be IE6 compatible:

HTML:

```
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td class="column">
        <p>Column 1, lorem ipsum dolor bla bla dogs and cats</p>
    </td>
    <td class="center-column"><div id='ie6-fix'></div></td>
    <td class="column">
        <p>Column 3, lorem blops dolor bla laa cats and dogs</p>                        
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

​
CSS:

```
.column {
    background: pink;
}
.center-column {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
#ie6-fix {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jmeas! I was skeptical when I saw `tables` but I see that this one's pretty clean. Will try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a robust css framework like YAML.

It alows you to develop columnar an responsive layouts with 2 or 3 columns. So, instead of trying to solve the cross-platform issues, you could focus in arts and development.

Check this out:
http://www.yaml.de/demos/flexible-columns.html

Comment: User doesn't seem to have been asking for a library recommendation

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.left, .right {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-container"> 
    <div class="left">
        <p>Column 1, lorem ipsum dolor bla bla dogs and cats</p>
    </div>
  
    <div></div>
  
    <div class="right">
        <p>Column 3, lorem blops dolor bla laa cats and dogs</p>                        
    </div>
<section>
```

This is an old post but I thought of sharing my thoughts for beginners like me...
I suggest adding an empty div between the two paragraphs in your html and use display grid in your css.  You can adjust the grid size the way you want it.